# how to include $count in condition in mongoose to achieve below result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose aggregate function to filter this below json and it  looks like:

for module/application 1

```
 [
    {
        "phase": "Knowledge Transfer",
        "Planned": 1,
        "Inprogress": 1,
        "Delayed": 0,
        "YetToStart": 0,
        "Complete": 1
    }
]
```

======
for module/application 2

```
[
    {
        "phase": "Knowledge Transfer",
        "Planned": 1,
        "Inprogress": 0,
        "Delayed": 0,
        "YetToStart": 0,
        "Complete": 0
    },
    {
        "phase": "Initiation",
        "Planned": 1,
        "Inprogress": 0,
        "Delayed": 0,
        "YetToStart": 1,
        "Complete": 1
    }]
```

====

(by adding )
resultant json should be like[Expected result],

```
 [
    {
        "phase": "Knowledge Transfer",
        "Planned": 2,
        "Inprogress": 1,
        "Delayed": 0,
        "YetToStart": 0,
        "Complete": 0
    },
    {
        "phase": "Initiation",
        "Planned": 1,
        "Inprogress": 0,
        "Delayed": 0,
        "YetToStart": 1,
        "Complete": 1
    }]
```

below is the query used:

```js
router.get("/:id/:category/:tower/:application", (req, res) => {
  var recentDate = new Date();
  Activity.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$phasename",
        MaxplannedEnd: {
          $max: "$plannedEndDate"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        Planned: {
          $cond: [{ $lte: ["$MaxplannedEnd", recentDate] }, 1, 0]
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
});
```

it always returns 1 ..how can i include $count here?

Comment: What is `MaxplannedEnd`, `phasename` and `recentDate`?

Comment: i have updated above.

Comment: can you share collection at jsoneditor online ?

Comment: yes.please check https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c5f0a4c73f614d399ff9e3bdf2e2d66b

Comment: Please share output collection at jsoneditor online ?

Comment: here is my output collection  https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c5f0a4c73f614d399ff9e3bdf2e2d66b

Comment: Please check both json same ?

Comment: i have edited my json now.for application1 https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c5f0a4c73f614d399ff9e3bdf2e2d66b and for application 2 https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c5f0a4c73f614d399ff9e3bdf2e2d66b

Comment: both data same please check ??

Comment: yes its same i checked .i am using a dropdown for application.If i use 'application 1' data for' application 1' ll be returned same for application 2.now if i give 'all application' the resultant should display by adding all application and grouping by phase .where my expected result i have mentioned above in the question section.